# Only ignore htaccess rule if file and filetype exists

Tags: .htaccess

I've done some code so that the url gets passed to the index page and the index page then decides which page to load in. Initially it would redirect unless a file or directory existed, which was fine for most cases, but things like the php files I wanted to keep private, as they should only be referenced by index.php, and not actually called themselves.

With a bit of help, I managed to switch it so that it would redirect everything, aside from certain extensions, such as images and css files. I've only just noticed it'll still attempt work on files that don't exist, and come up with the default 404 page, but I'd prefer it to be passed to my code like all the other pages.

How would I merge these two rules, so that the redirect will only not happen if both the file exists, and its extension is allowed?

```
1. RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
2. RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:jpe?g|gif|txt|php|bmp|png|ico|tiff|css|js)$
```

Here were the old rules (specific to the redirecting):

```
# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_page_location=$1 [L,NC,NE]
```

And here is it as it currently stands:

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L,NC]

# Add trailing slash to directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]

# If the request is not for known file types
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:jpe?g|gif|txt|php|bmp|png|ico|tiff|css|js)$

RewriteRule .* index.php?_page_location=$0 [L,QSA]

<FilesMatch "^(.*)\.php$">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "index\.php|info\.php">
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: You need to use the `[OR]` flag on the 1st `RewriteCond`  :)

Comment: Thanks, appears to have done the trick :)